# Scroll to top in RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment in which there is `RecyclerView` with `LinearLayoutManager` in which there are `CardView` items. There is a floating action button on clicking which the items should scroll to top. I have tried using `scrollToPosition` as well as `scrollToPositionWithOffset` with `RecyclerView` and also with `LinearLayoutManager` as shown below. But it has no effect at all. Why is this so? Can anyone please help me out.

And i have placed the `RecyclerView` directly inside the `SwipeRefreshView` in the xml file. I am calling `setFloatingActionButton` as soon as set adapter to `RecyclerView`.

```
 public void setFloatingActionButton(final View view) {
    float = (android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.float);
    float.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);


            android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(view, "Scrolled to Top", android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .setAction("Ok", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            LinearLayoutManager llm = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                            llm.scrollToPosition(0);

                        }
                    })
                    .setActionTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.coloLink))
                    .show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try `mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);`

Comment: yeah i have tried this .But this has no effect too just like scrollToPosition.

Comment: Thats strange, because even I had a similar layout as yours. I had a `RecyclerView` with layout manager and that was placed in a `SwipeRefreshview`, and that worked for me.

Comment: Is there any problem if i call scrollToPosition as soon as i set adapter to recyclerview?

Comment: But by default when you set the adapter to the `RecyclerView` for the very first time, the list is scrolled to the top. So you need not call `scrollToPosition` explicitly. Anyway try running it after some delay, by using some delay and check. `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)`

Comment: Now i placed  mlayoutmanager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0,0); outside the method setFloatingAction button and it works fine !!!

Comment: So is there any way i can use scroll to top when i click Floating Action Button?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Continuing from above comments, ideally, replacing

```
mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

in the `onClick` of the floating action button with

```
mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
```

should work. You can also remove the `SnackBar` code, because you don't need it anyways. So, all in all your above method should look like

```
public void setFloatingActionButton(final View view) {
    float actionButton = (android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton) getActivity()
            .findViewById(R.id.float);
    actionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView
                    .getLayoutManager();
            layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

And if you say that the above doesnt work, then test if the `onClick()` is even being called or not. Try adding a log message in it and see if its printed.

Comment: Yeah i actually got it by removing calls from other fragments to this method. I placed fab creation in onCreate() method directly.Its working completely fine now.

Comment: And with snackbar its not working. Thats fine as there is no need of snackbar.

Comment: This solution works only in first fragment.If i call setFloatingActionActionButton from both the fargments then scrollToTop works only in second fragment but not in first fragment.I am extending second fragment from first fragment.Can you plz help?

Comment: Why are you calling this in the fragment in the first place, and not from the activity?

Comment: How do i access mRecyclerView in the mainactivity and set mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0) from the main activity? i am new to android as well as java.I am learning lot of things while developing this app:)Thank You

Comment: Can you plz tell me how do i access mRecyclerView, which is in all the fragments, from main activity and set scrollToPosition(0) so that on clicking FAB in any fragment the recycler view scrolls to top??

Comment: Can you explain whether your mRecyclerView is placed in the fragments or the main activity? If possible please post the code for the fragments and the main activity, so that I can understand what the flow of your app is.

Comment: mRecyclerView is placed in the fragments.Each fragment has an instance of recyclerview but not FAB as it is placed in activity_main.So 
can you please tell me how do i access mRecyclerView, which is in all the fragments, from main activity and set scrollToPosition(0) so that on clicking FAB in any fragment the recycler view scrolls to top??

Comment: You must have an instances of the fragments in your MainActivity. Use that to access the `mRecyclerView`.

Comment: This is not working when the recylerview is set reverselayout() and stackfromend().

Answer (score 19):

Using the method `smoothScrollToPosition()` worked for me with the newest Android version.

```
layoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerView, null, 0);
```

Answer (score 6):

Call 'scrollToPosition(0)' using this:

```
public void scrollToPosition(final int position) {
    if (mRecyclerView != null) {
        getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
                if (position == 0) {
                    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                    layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
                    mScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is mScrollView..?

Comment: private NestedScrollView mScrollView;

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want smooth scroll this will work with any `LayoutManager`:

```java
myRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin

```
        // Scroll to the top of the list
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            delay(200)
            if (binding.rateList.size > 1) {
                //binding.recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
                binding.recyclerView.layoutManager?.scrollToPosition(0)
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the requirement was to populate the view in reverse order, which made the layout show the bottom view of the scroll view

`layoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerView, null, 'last_index')` didn't really help.

My problem was resolved when I made the recycler view to show the child at the last position

`recyclerView.scrollToPosition(length-1)`

Answer (score 1):

in `Kotlin` you can create `Extension` for RecyclerView:

```
fun RecyclerView.scrollToUp() = this.layoutManager?.scrollToPosition(0)
```

Now you can call this function on your `RecyclerView`:

```
yourRecyclerView.scrollToUp()
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions didn't work for me coz my recycler view was inside the NestedScrollView. So this solution worked for me.

```java
nestedScroll.smoothScrollTo(0,recycler.top)
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to have a RecyclerView in a NestedScrollView.

Comment: Recyclerview inside NestedScrollview results list not recycled but keep on adding. There is definitely lags in the application. Better to use Recyclerview alone.

Answer (score 0):

Some time user uses NestedScrollView for the NestedScrollView we can use below code .

```
 /*Scrolls NestedScrollView to the top of screen.*/
        viewBinding.scrollview.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP)
```

May be it can help to somebody in future.