# Scroll to the top of recyclerView in Android using a button

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, smooth-scrolling

I have used **recyclerView** in my application and want to add a **scroll up to top button** in that, I have added the button in it but could not be able to scroll my recyclerView on top when I clicks the button, also I have **reversed** my RecyclerView so that the new post I add in it comes on top not on bottom. please help me, much thanks in advance. I have also used `getPosition` method but that did not work for me.

> I am using Android Studio

**scroll action class file code:**

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private RecyclerViewPager mrecyclerView;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
private Button rollUp;
public static int recyclerPos = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("post");
    mrecyclerView = (RecyclerViewPager) findViewById(R.id.list);
    final LinearLayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(HomePage.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    layout.setReverseLayout(true);//<---- to get new posted data on top of list
    layout.setStackFromEnd(true);//<-----
    mrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layout);
    rollUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.roll_up);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    this.mrecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        int mLastFirstVisibleItem = 0;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            final int currentFirstVisibleItem = layout.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (currentFirstVisibleItem < this.mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                HomePage.this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
            } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem > this.mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                HomePage.this.getSupportActionBar().show();
            }
            this.mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;
        }
    });

}

    private void sentToStart() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(HomePage.this, LoginPage.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_page, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings){
        Intent intentSettings = new Intent(HomePage.this,settings.class);
        startActivity(intentSettings);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) mrecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
        recyclerPos = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    }
    if (id == R.id.roll_up){
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerroll = ((LinearLayoutManager) mrecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
        recyclerPos = layoutManagerroll.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        layoutManagerroll.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0,0);

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: This question has been asked many times before.

Comment: @H.Brooks can you refer some, i have tried many but they did not work for me and i was unable to get correct answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32159724/5550161

Comment: @H.Brooks i have reversed the recyclerView and the `scrollToPositionWithOffset` takes me to bottom of the page, please help with that

Comment: Ok since you keep adding items you should first get the amout of items then you can set the position of `scrollToPositionWithOffset` to the amout of items.

Comment: @H.Brooks how to achieve this, with a method?

Comment: Where are you storing the info that gets passed to the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @H.Brooks in firebase database using firebaseRecyclerAdapter

Comment: Ok you need to get the amount of items in your database by getting the id. If you haven't set a id for each you first have to do that. This gets complex when you delete items.

Comment: @H.Brooks i have set the id but how to get the items and set position to those?

Comment: @H.Brooks can you refer some example code so that it will be easier for me to understand

Comment: @rohitb check out me updated answer

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is that your position is wrong,** since you want to scroll to the top which is element at 0 position you have to **Do this** `mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);`
**Not this** `mrecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerPos.getItemCount()-1);`.
as you are scrolling to last but one element.
where the position is wrong

Also to **add a element at a particular position use this**   `addItemAtPosition() and don't callnotifyDataSetChanged()` no need to inverse the whole list like you have mentioned.