# How to scroll-to-top by tap the bottom navigation icon?

Tags: android

[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plVH8.jpg)

Hello guys
I use templater Bottom Navigation Activity and dont know how to scroll to top RecyclerView in my Home Fragment

My MainActivity code:

```
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll to top in RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159724/scroll-to-top-in-recyclerview-with-linearlayoutmanager)

Comment: I cant call scrollToPosition() in MainActivity, my RecycleView on another fragment

Comment: @fdai31.5 did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The question is quit old, but maybe it helps others.
This is the code you have to put in the fragment (in Kotlin):

```
val nav = activity?.findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation)
nav?.setOnItemReselectedListener { item ->
    if (item.itemId == R.id.mainFragment) {
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NavController, use this:

```
val parentFragment = (parentFragment as? NavHostFragment)?.parentFragment

val bottomNavigationView = if (parentFragment == null) {
    activity?.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
} else {
    parentFragment.view?.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
}

bottomNavigationView?.setOnItemReselectedListener { item ->
    if (item.itemId == fragmentId) {
       // scroll top recyclerView or something
    }
}
```

When obtaining the NavHostFragment, if your BottomNavigationView is inside a fragment, and then you use the NavController inside the fragment, then you must obtain the ParentFragment of your NavHostFragment that will return the parent Fragment.

I made it a little more generic, so if my ParentFragment is null, it means that the BottomNavigationView is in an activity.

Depending on the two cases, you simply use findViewById in different contexts.