# Refreshing data in RecyclerView and keeping its scroll position take user to the top of the activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement app like Instagram where user can like and share but when he press on a button (like image heart) .

> ```
> ///interface to get position
> ```

```
@Override
public void onitemclick(int position) {

     position_of_image=position;
    int num1=uploads.get(position_of_image).getNumber_likes();
    uploads.get(position_of_image).setNumber_likes(num1+1);

   String id=uploads.get(position_of_image).getId();
   int number= uploads.get(position_of_image).getNumber_likes();
   String name= uploads.get(position_of_image).getName();
   String url=uploads.get(position_of_image).getImageUrl();

   //updating the tables

   Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();
   map.put(id,new Upload(name,url,number,id));
//  mDatabaseRef.child(id).child("number_likes").setValue(number);
    uploads.clear();
    mDatabaseRef.updateChildren(map);
    mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position_of_image);
}
```

**and this is my interface on click in my adapter I want to make the like btn is red it done but disappears quickly **

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mlistener!=null){
            int position=getAdapterPosition();
            if (position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                mlistener.onitemclick(position);

            }
           like.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_heart);

        }


public interface  onlikeclic{
        void onitemclick(int position);


    }
    public void setonitemclicklistener(onlikeclic listener){
        mlistener=listener;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On item click, use call `RecyclerView`'s `smoothScrollToPosition(0)` method.

You can see an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32160022/6835732).