# How to always get to the top position after adding a note?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

When I click add note, the note gets to the top but I had to scroll up to check the note added.
It didn't go automatically as it should do. How can I implement this?
And there is an error which is being shown up when I tried to add note, i.e. index out of bound. But I solved it by setting itemAnimator to null.

**Notes.kt**

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.cashmates.daos.NoteDao
import com.example.cashmates.models.Note
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_notes.*

class Notes : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var noteDao: NoteDao
    private lateinit var adapter: NoteAdapter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes)

        fab.setOnClickListener {
        val intent3 = Intent(this, CreateNoteActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent3)
        }
    setUpRecyclerView()
    }

    private fun setUpRecyclerView() {
        noteDao = NoteDao()
        val notesCollections = noteDao.noteCollections
        val query = notesCollections.orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        val recyclerViewOptions = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>().setQuery(query, Note::class.java).build()

        adapter= NoteAdapter(recyclerViewOptions)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.itemAnimator = null
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        adapter.startListening()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        adapter.stopListening()
    }
}
```

NoteAdapter.kt

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.cashmates.models.Note
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

class NoteAdapter(options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note>) : FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Note, NoteAdapter.NoteViewHolder>(
options
) {
    class NoteViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val noteText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notes)
        val date: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dates)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteViewHolder {
        return NoteViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_note,parent,false))
}

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteViewHolder, position: Int, model: Note) {
        holder.noteText.text = model.detail
        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
        val dateString = simpleDateFormat.format(model.time)
        holder.date.text = dateString.toString()
    }

}
```

I am not able to automatically come to the top of the linear layout, I had to scroll the linear layout to go to the top.

Comment: Are you asking how to scroll a recycler view to the top? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159724/scroll-to-top-in-recyclerview-with-linearlayoutmanager

Comment: I want to implement it in my code. how do I implement it?

Comment: Have you tried Frank van Puffelen's suggestion?

Comment: @AlexMamo the solution Frank van Puffelen told me is in java and I want it in kotlin.

Comment: Android Studio can simply convert Java code into Kotlin code.

Comment: @AlexMamo it doesn't help. I tried all the solution but still it is not going to the top position after adding a note.